# NoMethodError from jasmine-headless-webkit

Tags: jasmine-headless-webkit

I am suddenly seeing this while running jasmine-headless-webkit in my rails app:

dhcp-10-154-148-96:lic_engine_app smadhan$ jasmine-headless-webkit
NoMethodError: undefined method `color' for "jasmine-headless-webkit":String
    run! at /Users/smadhan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/lib/jasmine/headless/command_line.rb:23
  (root) at /Users/smadhan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/bin/jasmine-headless-webkit:10
    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1073
  (root) at /Users/smadhan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jasmine-headless-webkit:23

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

It might be the wrong version of Rainbow installed in your gemset.

Try the following:

```
gem list|grep rainbow
```

If you have >2.0.0 version, you need to downgrade:

```
gem uninstall rainbow
gem install rainbow --version 1.99.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The project repository says that it's dead, and that you should use [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io) instead: https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit/commit/f7384d684ca8974bcadcf318427f07c4b66b3c68